# How I can covert this hexadecimal values to pixel values

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, hex, pixel, hid

While I'm reading data from an `HID device` for `X` and `Y` axis values, getting the X & Y axis data in `Hexadecimal` value. How I can covert this hexadecimal values to `pixel` values.

Comment: How are you receiving the Hexadecimal data? It just seems weired, because computers don't work in Hex: the device would need to turn it's data (binary) into Hex, knowing the receiving side will need to turn it back into binary because it can't work with Hex. I'm just curious.

Comment: Hi Cosmin, find the vc++ code below for reading data `   if(retByte != 0)
   {
    Button = HIDData[1] & 0x01;
    TmpLow = (int)HIDData[2];
    TmpHigh = (int)HIDData[3];
    LastX = (TmpLow & 0x00FF) | ((TmpHigh << 8) & 0xFF00);
    TmpLow = (int)HIDData[4];
    TmpHigh = (int)HIDData[5];
    LastY = (TmpLow & 0x00FF) | ((TmpHigh << 8) & 0xFF00);
    XYData = LastX | LastY << 16;
    counter++;
 
    ::PostMessage(pInfo->h_MainView, WM_USER_DATA_IN, Button, XYData);
   }'

Comment: I don't see any hex data here. Cosmin is right, you question indicates serious misunderstanding. You need to get to the bottom of that first.

Comment: What do you think it's hex in there? The string you're seeing on screen is decimal formated (it'd be hex if you'd see A,B,C,D,E,F in there). The `%.5d` simply tells `Format` to use a minimum of 5 digits when displaying the number (that gives you the leading 0). The only hex in your code are the constants 0xFF00 and 0x00FF - but those are constants, you can use them in Delphi like this: $FF00 and $00FF, you don't need to do any kind of conversion. The rest is just bitwise manipulation (shift left, or, and).

Comment: Cosmin, Could you please give me your Instant Message ID, I will give more details on my issue. Please help me.

Comment: I can't do that, I don't like instant messaging; But fell free to edit this question (or ask a new one) and I'll answer it the best that I can.

Comment: @Able If you can spend the time to ask a clearer, better explained question, then there'd be no need for IM and you'd probably understand it yourself. You are giving up too soon I feel.

Comment: @Able I'm sorry, I have no experience working with any HID devices. And I think you're confusing the questions: Your question about [How to programmatically change Tablet PC Orientation is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895179/how-to-programmatically-change-tablet-pc-orientation), this question is about converting some Hex values. If you think the function provided by the supplier can be of any value in solving the problem, try asking a "what does this C code do" question, they're allowed on SO and it will get answers.

Comment: ok, thanks all, i will try to find out solution.

Comment: Able; this question is missing a lot of detail and it is basically unanswerable.   It suggests to me that you either need to expand your question, or that you don't understand what it is that you are trying to do.  What HID device do you have and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Warren,I'm using DigiMemoA4 Digital Notepad HID Device. For more information just google it. With this device we can write notes using a digital pen and the same time we can see the hand writing contents  in my application. I'm using `InkPicture` component to see the handwriting matters.Up to this all are fine.The issue is,whatever i'm writing horizontally in Digital notepad its showing vertically in `'Inkpicture` control. So I need to Change the `orientation` of digital notepad from '`Landscape' to `Vertical`. This is my requirement. I suppose u understand.

Comment: @Able Alias - please update your question with the extra information in your comments. It may be easier for others to answer it and also better for anybody looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a hex string? like '5A'.
if so ive found sucess with this

```
function HexToInt(HexNum: string): LongInt;
begin
   Result:=StrToInt('$' + HexNum) ;
end;
```